# Gulp Watch not working for new ubuntu setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gulp, ubuntu-18.04

I installed a fresh ubuntu 18.04  box and tried to use gulp for a new project but i'm running into issues with gulp.watch() not watching for changes.

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./css/*.sass')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/compiled'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});
gulp.task('watch',function(){
    gulp.watch('./css/*.sass', gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch('./css/*.sass',browserSync.reload);
})
gulp.task('watchAll', gulp.series('watch'));
```

folder structure:

```
-css
   -compiled
       main.css
   all-pages.sass
-images
index.html
gulpfile.js
package.json
package-lock.json
```

```
$ node -v
v13.2.0

$ npm -v
6.13.1

$ gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2

$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic
```

This gulpfile i reuse for many different projects and it usually works out of the box except for this instance when i have it on a new Ubuntu installation. 
Is i just run the task 'sass', it works. it will look through the sass files and compile them down to css and put them into a main.css, but watch will not work, it just does not detect any changes i make.

I created my Ubuntu instance with vagrant + VMBox

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It was because i was using a shared folder between windows && linux. just needed to add the `usePolling:true` to my watch functions.

`gulp.watch('./styles/*.sass',{ usePolling: true }, gulp.series('sass'));`